# Increase Allowable File Path Length

Tags: installation, nsis

Is it possible to increase the file path/string length for NSIS? I am attempting to use the function `FILE` with a path that is rather long and I get the compile error:

`File: failed opening file "..\..\..\..\12d\10.00\DPTI_Customisation\\DESIGN_12d10\DPTI_Design_User\DPTI_D_Toolbars\DPTI_D_Create_D_Boundaries_for_Tin.slx"`

Is it possible to increase the allowable length like how you can increase the $NSIS_MAX_STRLEN varaible length?

This [thread](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=320618) says that the error is caused by the file path being too long.

**Edit**
Heres the code:

```
FILE /r "..\..\..\..\12d\10.00\DPTI_Customisation\"
# The folder DPTI_Customisation contains many sub folders and files
```

Comment: Could you also post the path this file is relative to? And are you using File /r or just File?

Comment: @Anders please see the edit that now shows my code :)

Comment: What is the full path to DPTI_D_Create_D_Boundaries_for_Tin.slx?

Comment: @Anders Its D:\Data\12d\10.00\DPTI_Customisation\DESIGN_12d10\DPTI_Design_User\DPTI_D_Toolbars\DPTI_D_Create_D_Boundaries_for_Tin.slx.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the unicode version of NSIS.

Alternatively, I wonder if you could use multiple calls to `cd` in order to reduce your path length.

Ref: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#5.1.5

Comment: thanks for the answer. Why cant NSIS just allow long file paths?

Comment: @JakeM There's a windows limitation of 160 characters if you don't use the unicode API. That's why someone has spun off an Unicode enabled version of NSIS.

Comment: The limit is 260 (MAX_PATH) and it also applies to Unicode unless you use the \\?\ prefix...

Comment: @Anders can I use the \\?\ prefix in ASCII versions? I cant go straight to Unicode because the XML plugins dont work for Unicode files