# How to use NSIS Unicode \\?\ prefix for long pathnames

Tags: unicode, path, nsis

I'm using NSIS for installer creation, but have a problem with long pathnames (>260 characters). I've heard of an unicode version, which can handle long pathnames with a special prefix `\\?\`.
I wonder if there's any docs describing what the `\\?\` prefix does and how it is used. I am  using `File /r /x root ..*` in the non-unicode NSIS version.

The same problem is described here [Increase Allowable File Path Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536817/increase-allowable-file-path-length) but no real solution.

OS is Windows 7, the error message is

```
File: failed opening file "..\server\WEB-INF\classes\some\very\long\and\winding\path\myFile.txt"
Error in script "D:\real\long\path\to\nsis\my.nsis.updater.nsi" on line 116 -- aborting creation process
```

This line is the call of

```
File /r /x nsis ..\*
```

which packs my content.

Comment: What is your OS? What problem do you encounter? Any error message?

Comment: You are not the only one that has a problem, your user will too.  With programs failing that you probably never even heard about.  Like some kind of backup utility or search indexer.  Just don't do this unless you like getting support calls that are *very* hard to answer.  Who does?

Comment: I don't think the user will have the problem too, because NSIS complains that the overall path is too long. If I put my base path to c:\tmp all is fine. The relative path from my project root is much shorter than the max path limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Unicode NSIS fork](http://www.scratchpaper.com/) has some support for long paths but I'm not sure if the compiler part of `File` is one of them.

There are a couple of reasons why the official NSIS does not support long paths:

- The `\\?\` prefix tells Windows to not parse the path at all in user-mode so you lose support for relative paths. We would then have to implement our own path parser with relative path support. It also means we have to allocate memory and parse/expand to the full path every time a path is used.
- `Exec*` (`CreateProcess` / `ShellExecute`), `CreateShortcut` (`IShellLink`) and `CopyFiles` (`SHFileOperation`) don't support long paths so some instructions would support long paths and some would not. This means end-users could install a .exe in a folder where it cannot be executed!

You can probably create some code that extracts a file to $pluginsdir and then uses the system plugin to call kernel32::CreateDirectory and kernel32::MoveFile with the long destination path directly...

Comment: I do not yet understand why NSIS needs the *complete* path while packing my files. From my point of view the NSIS compiler has to start from one root location, ok, but from then the path to consider is just the part coming after the root. The packed file structure does surely not know about from where on the creator's disk it was packed, only the directory tree under the creation root are stored. Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: What the NSIS compiler does is not really the point, "\\?\..\abc" is not a valid path because the \\?\ prefix only works with full paths so any program that wants to exceed the MAX_PATH (260) limit needs to provide the absolute path to the Windows functions it is calling. In your example MakeNSIS would end up calling FindFirstFile("\\?\..\\*") and that would fail. FindFirstFile("..\\*") will work but then you are back to the MAX_PATH limitation you are already hitting.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the documentation about paths in [MSDN: Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx).